# Remove the white and black screen when starting the Android application made with Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

> Unity:2017.2.1f1
>   Device:ASUS_Z017DA(Android 8.0.0)

We want to shorten the Android application launch time.
We upgraded to Unity Plus for that.

We have confirmed the operation with minimum application.
We just created a new project, changed package name and hidden splash screen.

> - Player Settings - Other Settings - Identification - Package Name(Modify)
> - Player Settings - Splash Image - Splash Screen - Show Splash Screen(Uncheck)

However, when you start an Android application, the screen of 3 kinds of colors is displayed on the screen.

[Movie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QaZY6kS1RlXWXjK5dH0sX8paZczxeAST/view)

> - White -> Black -> Blue(314D7900)

The last Blue (314D7900) screen is the default scene.
It is the background color of the main camera.
We do not regard it as a problem.

We do not like the screen of White and Black.
We feel these are not beautiful.
Is it possible to remove them?

If we can not erase them, Is it possible to shorten these display times?
If we can not shorten those display times, Is it possible to change those colors?

As we further advance the implementation, these display times will be even longer.
We tried various settings and created a loading scene.
But We could not improve them.

Even though we saw other released applications, it did not look like this.
Did we do something wrong?

We tried these.
We checked and unchecked the Splash Screen.
We checked and unchecked the Unity Logo.
We tried to create a loading scene.

But they only slowed the startup speed.
We just want to know how to start simple and fast.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question with more detail about what the app does and what you've tried. It may help to benchmark parts of the app to see what is taking up time/resources. Possibly related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132832/can-i-run-my-own-loading-script-during-the-unity-splash-screen

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
We add more details.

Answer (score 4):

White -> Black -> Blue(314D7900) is caused by your theme and  activity's layout background.

In your app's manifest file, check your activity's or application's android:theme attribute, such as `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Then open the `AppTheme` style, add a windowBackground or android:windowBackground set the color to Blue:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
  </style>
```

Then in your main activity's layout file, I think you set a black background color, now remove the background.

Now start you app, you will see just the Blue background.

Because you not post your code, that's my best guess. If not solve your problem, please share your project in Github, I can check where is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Because we have not changed any files generated by Unity. We will try adapt the way you taught to the project generated by Unity.